# Compile a node using the C++ sound_play API and catkin

Tags: ros, c++, catkin, ros-groovy, play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

So, I have been trying for a moment to compile a catkin package written in C++ which would use the sound_play package API, but it seems never to find the header <sound_play/sound_play.h>, even though the sound_play package is installed and works normally through rosrun. I have tried to use rosmake in the sound_play package, and can see that the header is indeed in the right place, but still catkin can't find it. Maybe I am forgetting to add an include somewhere?
This is ROS groovy I am using.

Thanks for any suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192789/compile-a-node-using-the-c++-sound_play-api-and-catkin/) by [hiro64](https://answers.ros.org/users/20213/hiro64/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2014-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hiro64](https://answers.ros.org/users/20213/hiro64/) on 2014-09-18**:
If anyone gets into this situation, I have solved it by taking the headers (sound_play.h and SoundRequest.h) directly from the sound_play package and using them as part of the src of my package. This way, one is able to use their functions and the SoundClient class.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-09-18**:
That is probably not a solution we should recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sound_play in Groovy is a rosbuild package. You can only depend on it from other rosbuild packages, not from catkin. Sorry.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hiro64](https://answers.ros.org/users/20213/hiro64/) on 2014-09-16**:
Oh, how sad for me haha But thanks.
Would you happen to know any other way for me to either synthesize voice or play sound files using catkin on groovy?